# Where is SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS defined?

Tags: c++, winapi

I came across a [short C++ code designed to prevent applications from stealing focus using DLL injection](https://superuser.com/q/18383/194976). As usual with C++, I have problems with things being undefined and libraries being missing.

Specifically, this constant is undefined: `SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS`. In this code:

```
typedef NTSTATUS( WINAPI* PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION ) ( 
  __in       SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,     
  __inout    PVOID SystemInformation, 
  __in       ULONG SystemInformationLength, 
  __out_opt  PULONG ReturnLength    
);
```

The `windows.h` is already included so it must be something else missing. When googling that, I got lot of results about getting the CPU temperature, but I can't see what should I include in them...

Comment: Docs are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx and include a header file reference. But this is a private API. You may find that the header cannot easily be found, or doesn't have all you need. Be prepared to roll up your sleeves.

Comment: What does it mean that it's private API? Does one have to buy it?

Comment: No, it's just not completely documented, and has weak support in the SDK. You are in the wild west now.

Comment: "Native api" is the proper term.  Windows internally looks very different from what you are used to seeing in the documented Winapi.  You are taking a dependency on a barely documented function that Microsoft doesn't promise it will keep compatible in future versions.  Only reason that Winternal.h exists is because they were forced to document *some* of it by the USA Department of Justice.  "Use the CryptGenRandom function instead" is a joke.

Comment: In USA, government can force companies to document their libraries?

Comment: Judges can force companies to do things they don't want to do.  The DoJ had a strong case, Microsoft was using this function in their own products.  That's unfair competition, illegal under the USA anti-trust law.  The EU has very similar laws.

Comment: @Hans My point is that this part of the native API is private. At least intended to be until the courts stepped in. Did the judgement really allow them to make stuff up (CryptGenRandom) and pretend that it was real documentation. You'd think that the courts would have enforced them to do it meaningfully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx), this enum is defined in the `Winternl.h` header file. The definition in the header file from the version 7.1 SDK is:

```
typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    SystemBasicInformation = 0,
    SystemPerformanceInformation = 2,
    SystemTimeOfDayInformation = 3,
    SystemProcessInformation = 5,
    SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation = 8,
    SystemInterruptInformation = 23,
    SystemExceptionInformation = 33,
    SystemRegistryQuotaInformation = 37,
    SystemLookasideInformation = 45
} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;
```

This NT API function is somewhat under documented. There are other values which you can find by searching online. As to how to use those other values, again you may need to take a leap of faith and rely on reverse engineered information that you can find from a web search.

Using undocumented functionality is risky business. Do not be surprised if Microsoft change or remove functionality in a future release, thus breaking your program. You might care to think twice before using undocumented functionality, or functionality that is documented as being liable to change in the future. Again, the documentation that I linked to does warn you about that in this way:

> NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic.

Comment: So it looks like in this is type `USHORT` huh?

Comment: @Noitidart Er, no. C enum will have base type int.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found [some SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS definition](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/system%20information/system_information_class.html) using [search terms "*`typedef SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS`*"](https://www.google.cz/search?q=typedef%20SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS). Though at the time of posting this, my own question is 3rd result...

Here's what I've got:

```
typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    SystemBasicInformation,
    SystemProcessorInformation,
    SystemPerformanceInformation,
    SystemTimeOfDayInformation,
    SystemPathInformation,
    SystemProcessInformation,
    SystemCallCountInformation,
    SystemDeviceInformation,
    SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation,
    SystemFlagsInformation,
    SystemCallTimeInformation,
    SystemModuleInformation,
    SystemLocksInformation,
    SystemStackTraceInformation,
    SystemPagedPoolInformation,
    SystemNonPagedPoolInformation,
    SystemHandleInformation,
    SystemObjectInformation,
    SystemPageFileInformation,
    SystemVdmInstemulInformation,
    SystemVdmBopInformation,
    SystemFileCacheInformation,
    SystemPoolTagInformation,
    SystemInterruptInformation,
    SystemDpcBehaviorInformation,
    SystemFullMemoryInformation,
    SystemLoadGdiDriverInformation,
    SystemUnloadGdiDriverInformation,
    SystemTimeAdjustmentInformation,
    SystemSummaryMemoryInformation,
    SystemNextEventIdInformation,
    SystemEventIdsInformation,
    SystemCrashDumpInformation,
    SystemExceptionInformation,
    SystemCrashDumpStateInformation,
    SystemKernelDebuggerInformation,
    SystemContextSwitchInformation,
    SystemRegistryQuotaInformation,
    SystemExtendServiceTableInformation,
    SystemPrioritySeperation,
    SystemPlugPlayBusInformation,
    SystemDockInformation,
    SystemPowerInformation,
    SystemProcessorSpeedInformation,
    SystemCurrentTimeZoneInformation,
    SystemLookasideInformation


} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PSYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;
```

Being unable to compile anything, I can't be sure it's correct. I just created new `.hpp` file and added the code above to it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to this: http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/query.htm.

There is a good description for `[Nt]|[Zw]QuerySystemInformation` and input arguments.